# Proving additivity of Bernoulli binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

This is about proving the additivity of Bernoulli's binomial distribution.
On another words,

$$X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p),\quad Y\sim\mathrm{Bin}(m,p)$$

implies that
$$ X+Y\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n+m,p).$$

meaning, if $X$ and $Y$ are in binomial distribution, with different population and the same success probability, the distribution of $X+Y$ is also binomial with $X+Y\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n+m,p)$.

And I can't understand the fourth line, where I marked '?'.  What concept should I learn more to understand this?

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(U+V=k) &= \sum_{j=0}^k \mathbb P(U=j,V=k-j)\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^k \mathbb P(U=j)\mathbb P(V=k-j)\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^k \binom nj p^j(1-p)^{n-j}\binom m{k-j}p^{k-j}(1-p)^{m-k+j}\\
&= p^k(1-p)^{n+m-k}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom nj \binom m{k-j}\quad \quad\mathbf ?\\
&= \binom {n+m}k p^k(1-p)^{n+m-k}.
\end{align}

Comment: you can use moment generating functions to prove it. The proof you've shown us uses the combinatorial identity $\sum_{j=0}^k \begin{pmatrix}
n\\
j\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
m\\
k-j\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}
n+m\\
k\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @fGDu94 Thank you!

Comment: You need to assume that $X,Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Chu-Vandermonde Identity (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_Identity). In general the addition of two binomial distribution is a special case of the Poisson Binomial distribution ([Addition of two Binomial Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153576/addition-of-two-binomial-distribution))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without any calculation. It depends on definitions, but most would already know that that a binomial distribution, with parameters $n$ and $p$, is defined as the sum of $n$ iid Bernoulis each with parameter $p$.  Your $X+Y$ then is the sum of $n':=n+m$ iid Bernoulis each with parameter $p$ and hence is binomially distributed.